# Keyboard opens when start the fragment and scroll

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have a scrollview in my fragment and when the fragment opens the keyboard appears automatically and focuses on the first edittext of the layout, and the screen scroll and I cannot see all the fields while the keyboard is opend.
So what can I do to prevent the Keyboard from appearing when the fragment starts and also what can I do to see all the fields in the scrollview with the keyboard opened?

Thanks

That's part of the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/personalDataLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
tools:context=".presentation.fragments.PersonalDataFragment">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: Could you post some code so we can see what your set up is? Just the minimum required to display that fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The highest level View that is focusable will be focused. EditTexts pull up the keyboard if it is focused. But if you add the following to your parent View (RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, etc) then the keyboard will not automatically be opened

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Example:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:focusable="true"
   android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: Cool, this works with the keyboard opening, but I still have the problem that when I open the keyboard the scrollView scrolls and I cannot see the top edittexts